# Entity Framework Navigation Property Updating Issue

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a model I am trying to write to my database. I can update the properties of the model to the database, but when I change a property in the navigation properties model, it does not update unless I manually set the state of the navigation property to modified.

```
public void UpdateFreq(FREQUENCY vm)
    {
        context.FREQUENCIES.Attach(item);
            context.Entry(vm).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

         context.Entry(vm.FREQ_POOL).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;//the navigation property
        _uow.Save();
    }
```

This used to work without having to do this in another project, but I cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I just want it to automatically set all the navigation properties of the model to modified as well. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: The first question should be: why do you want to set this state in the first place? EF is perfectly capable of managing the state itself. Secondly, changing an entity's state has always only affected the scalar properties of the entity.

Comment: I don't WANT to change it. I just want it to update the attached tables properties when they are changed. All I am trying to do is modify a property in a navigation table and have it update when I update the parent. The state is detached at this point, so if I don't set it, it won't update at all.